# Comparing property value in struts 2

Tags: struts2

I want to compare a session variable with a property value in test method of struts if condition.

```
<s:property value="band"/>
<s:if test="#session.bandname == property value">
    <s:form action="BandPost">
        <s:textarea key="post" accesskey="post">Write a post</s:textarea>
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form> 
</s:if>
```

I want to compare the above property value in if condition with #session.bandname value. I tried many things but they are not working. Can somebody give me the answer?

Thanks.

Comment: If bandname is a string use String methods (such as 'equals')... ie: test="#session.bandname.equals(propertyValue)".

Comment: I want to get "<s:property value="band"/>" value in test condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reference the property. You only need the **public String getBand()** Method in your Action.

```
<s:property value="band"/>
<s:if test="%{#session.bandname == band}">
    <s:form action="BandPost">
        <s:textarea key="post" accesskey="post">Write a post</s:textarea>
        <s:submit/>
    </s:form> 
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [core JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/tld-summary.html) can solve this problem easily.

```
<c:set var="varForComparison" value="ABC" scope="page"></c:set>

<c:if test="${ sessionScope.varInSession eq pageScope.varForComparison }">
 // DO WHAT YOU HAVE TO
</c:if>
```

you can even compare bean in request directly like this

```
<c:if test="${ sessionScope.varInSession eq requestScope.beanInRequest.propertyToCompare }">
 // DO WHAT YOU HAVE TO
</c:if>
```

Also if you want multiple conditions like if-else ladder, you can use this

```
<c:choose>
  <c:when test=""></c:when>
  <c:otherwise></c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

In c:choose, you can use as many c:when's as you want.
   Core JSTL + expression language helps a lot.
   Hope it helps.